# how can i change row color in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export class EstimateForm extends React.Component<IEstimateFormProps, 
IEstimateFormState> {
state: IEstimateFormState = {
cellUpdateCss: 'red',
toRow: null,
fromRow: null,
estimateList: null,
estimateItemList: [],
poseList: null,
levelList: null,
partList: null,
selectedEstimate: null,
totalEstimateItems: 0,
selectedIndexes: [],
totalEstimateAmount: 0,
grid: null,
projectId: 0,
};


constructor(props, context) {
super(props, context);
this.state.estimateList = this.props.estimateList;
}  


rowGetter = i => {
const row = this.state.estimateItemList[i];
const selectRevison = this.state.selectedEstimate.revision;
if (row['pose.poseName']) {
  const poseCode = row['pose.poseName'].substring(row['pose.poseName'].lastIndexOf('[') + 1, row['pose.poseName'].lastIndexOf(']'));
  for (const pose of this.state.poseList) {
    if (pose.poseCode === poseCode) {
      row.pose = pose;
    }
  }
}

if (row['level.levelName']) {
  const levelCode = row['level.levelName'].substring(
    row['level.levelName'].lastIndexOf('[') + 1,
    row['level.levelName'].lastIndexOf(']')
  );
  for (const level of this.state.levelList) {
    if (level.levelCode === levelCode) {
      row.level = level;
    }
  }
}

if (row['level.part.partName']) {
  const partCode = row['level.part.partName'].substring(
    row['level.part.partName'].lastIndexOf('[') + 1,
    row['level.part.partName'].lastIndexOf(']')
  );
  for (const part of this.state.partList) {
    if (part.partCode === partCode) {
      row.part = part;
    }
  }
}

row.get = key => eval('row.' + key);
row.totalCost = (row.materialCost + row.laborCost) * row.amount;
if (row.revision > selectRevison) {
    for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
      row[i].style.color = 'red';    // here color is nor change
    }
    return row;
  } else {
    return row;     
  }

  }

handleGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated }) => {
const rows = this.state.estimateItemList.slice();

for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
  const rowToUpdate = rows[i];
  const updatedRow = update(rowToUpdate, { $merge: updated });
  rows[i] = updatedRow;
}

this.setState({ estimateItemList: rows, fromRow: (fromRow), toRow: (toRow) 
 }, () => {
 });

};

saveEstimateItems = () => {
if (this.state.selectedEstimate == null) {
  toast.warn(<Translate 
 contentKey="bpmApp.estimateForm.pleaseSelectEstimate">Please select an 
 estimate</Translate>);
  return;
}



render() {

return ()
}
```

I wanna to change the row color when the condition row.revision > this.state.selectedEstimate.revision . How can I prevent the change of this.color. However im not get any error but row color is not change. how can i solve this problem it is my first project in react and i dont know where is the problemThanks for your feedback guys.